# Summation over elements

Tags: summation

I want to write a sum over "i" whose limits are like "i" starting 1 to 10 but "i" not equal to 2. How to write this?

Comment: I see at least three ways to do it: `Sum[If[i == 2, 0, f[i]], {i, 1, 10}]` or `Sum[Piecewise[{i == 2, 0}, {i != 2, f[i]}], {i, 1, 10}]` or just sum from 3 to 10 and add the one: `Sum[f[i],{i,3,10}] + f[1]`

Comment: `Total[f /@ Delete[Range[10], 2]]`

Answer (score 3):

```
f /@ Cases[Except[2]]@Range[10] // Total


Sum[f[i]*Boole[i != 2], {i,10}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sum[m+17, {m, Range[10] /. 2 -> Nothing}]
```